# Decode weird characters by pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I'm playing with pdf.js to convert pdf into text. I noticed some weird characters are displayed, but only in the HTML.

When they are rendered, the correct content appears (human readable text).

However, if I use `innerHTML` to get the content, I get weird stuff.

> [image]

The part of code generating this HTML is taken from [here](http://git.macropus.org/2011/11/pdftotext/), and is:

```
this.pdfToText = function(data) {
   var div = document.getElementById('viewer');

   // render the first pages
   var pdf = new PDFJS.PDFDoc(data);
   var total = pdf.numPages;

   for (i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
       var page = pdf.getPage(i);

       var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
       document.body.appendChild(canvas);
       canvas.id = 'page' + i;
       canvas.mozOpaque = true;
       div.appendChild(canvas);

       canvas.width = page.width;
       canvas.height = page.height;

       var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
       context.save();
       context.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
       context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
       context.restore();

       self.setMessage("Rendering...");

       var textLayer = document.createElement('div');
       textLayer.className = 'textLayer';
       document.body.appendChild(textLayer);

       page.startRendering(context, function() {
           if (++self.complete == total) {
               self.setMessage("Finished rendering. Extracting text...");

               window.setTimeout(function() {
                   var layers = [];
                   var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".textLayer > div");
                   for (var j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {
                       layers.push(nodes[j].textContent + "\n");
                   }
                   self.sendOutput(layers.join("\n"));

                   self.setMessage("Done!");
               }, 1000);
           }
       }, textLayer);
   }
};
```

How to decode these characters into human readable text and store the value into a variable?

Comment: Presumably pdf.js could not determine the correct encoding (because it can't do such a thing, or maybe it can but the encoding was not in the PDF to begin with) and created an ad hoc encoding and accompanying font file. "Decode into human readable text" can only be done manually, and per (subset of) font, by noting down what code to replace with what character.

Comment: The code you are using as a base is *too* old. Please use modern library and see better example at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/text-only . It's hard to tell if the PDF or library at fault please provide as much details as possible, otherwise your questions has too many answers like above or "don't use XXX"

Comment: @async5 I used that example and it worked well. Can you post an answer so you will get some points? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of PDF.js that is used in the example above is old -- new versions add the text extraction API, e.g. getTextContext(). Please see better example at http://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/text-only